# C++ building custom defines

Tags: c++, command, cmake

How can I add custom commands to the `cmake` when invoking something like

`cmake -G"Visual Studio 9 2008"`

I wish to be able to handle the case when the supplied library finder / configurator works wrong and I want to override the corresponding variables like

```
set BOOST_DIRECTORY = C:\boobs\
```

*to solve problems like `no boost libraries wer found`.*

***I wish I could have found the corresponding way myself, but I couldn't.***

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CMake gui programs to interactively set Cache values:

`ccmake`

or alternatively:

`cmake-gui`

Answer (score 1):

To pass variables on the command line use the -D switch like:

`cmake -G"Visual Studio 9 2008" -DBOOST_DIRECTORY="PATH"`